# Word for "left alone and to die"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, past-participles

Is there a word that means "left alone and to die"?

Edit: I believe there is such a word. I think I'm looking for abandoned and alone. Others expectations are that you'll die.

Comment: Do you mean "left alone to die"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Neglected* immediately comes to mind (particularly in the context of elderly people in hospitals), my Thesaurus is also suggesting *condemned* which would fit better in the context of a prisoner on death row although a building can also be declared unfit and condemned. *Forsaken* might also work depending on context (it has many Biblical connotations).

Answer (score 22):

Apart from the obvious close-but-no-cigar candidates [*abandoned*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abandon) and [*forsaken*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forsake), how about [*marooned*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maroon)?

> 1. [put] ashore on a desolate island or coast and [left] to one's fate
> 2. [placed or left] in isolation or without hope of ready escape

Comment: Like this one: http://xkcd.com/123/

Answer (score 7):

I cannot think of anything that specifically means “to leave someone alone to die”, even though “leave alone” has many synonyms. The closest I can think of are:

- **“to be left for dead”**: to be abandoned as certain to die, but it can also have the connotation of “almost dead”, which may or may not be desirable depending on the context
- **“to leave him to his fate”**: although it does not imply death in particular, it is usually implied that the fate in question is unfavourable
- **strand**, which means leave someone without means to move, may also be relevant in some cases (*stranded on an deserted island*)

Answer (score 1):

**Perhaps [castaway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castaway) is sufficient**

Sailors were cast away onto desert islands with the intention that they would suffer a slow and painful death, or go mad (although that is technically being marooned).